# Why Azure function throw errors of swaggerdocumentationkey?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app-proxy

Azure function App `butteryflyfnapp`
URL
https://butteryflyfnapp.azurewebsites.net
App Service plan / pricing tier
butteryflyfnserviceplan (Standard)

Keep throwing the below errors, why?

> Error:
>
> We are not able to get the key swaggerdocumentationkey. Please check the runtime logs for any errors or try again later.
>   Session Id: 1cd3f82f0430463c852c1ff04cfc094f
>
> Timestamp: 2017-11-09T08:59:19.954Z
>
> Error:
>
> We are not able to retrieve the runtime master key. Please try again later.
>   Session Id: 1cd3f82f0430463c852c1ff04cfc094f
>
> Timestamp: 2017-11-09T08:59:29.698Z

And my function `Nodes_Current_State_Report_Fn_App` of `butteryflyfnapp` log output as following,

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Service Unavailable</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```